# GLFW can't find VK_KHR_win32_surface in MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, glfw, vulkan

#### Description

Currently my program runs on MSVC without any problems but on MinGW `glfwCreateWindowSurface(...)` strangely throws an error that it's missing the `VK_KHR_win32_surface` extension.

#### Surface Code

```
void createSurface() {
    if (glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create window surface!");
    }
}
```

#### Additional Info

- `vkGetInstanceProcAddr(..., "vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR")` and `glfwGetInstanceProcAddress(..., "vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR")`: return a non-null function pointer
- `glfwGetError(...)`: returns `65542` and `Win32: Vulkan instance missing VK_KHR_win32_surface extension`
- `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(...)`: lists the `VK_KHR_win32_surface` extension
- `glfwCreateWindowSurface(...)`: returns `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT`
- `glfwVulkanSupported()`: returns 1
- It should be the same code as https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/26_depth_buffering.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using GLFW Native since it works:

```cpp
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

// ...

VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR surfaceInfo {};
surfaceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
surfaceInfo.hinstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
surfaceInfo.hwnd = glfwGetWin32Window(window);

if (vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(instance, &surfaceInfo, nullptr, &surface) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create window surface!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you have an older glfw?

I have the `glfwCreateWindowSurface` present in **glfw3**.

I built glfw3 myself (both static and shared library) with MinGW-w64 in the MSYS2 shell from the source file at
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/glfw/glfw/3.3.2/glfw-3.3.2.tar.bz2 using these commands:

```
cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_static &&
cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_shared &&
make -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
make -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
echo Success
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application is using the proper Vulkan library for your target platform. With MinGW targeting Windows you therefore may need to manually link against `vulkan-1.dll`.